# How do you fade in/out a background color using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, fade

How do I fade in text content with jQuery?

The point is to draw the user's attention to the message.

Comment: you can start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ColorAnimations

Comment: You don't have to use the color or UI plugins for animating background color. I've answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694295/jquery-background-color-animate-not-working/5718151#5718151).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This exact functionality (3 second glow to highlight a message) is implemented in the jQuery UI as the highlight effect

https://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

Color and duration are variable

Comment: $('newCommentItem').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

Comment: Another example, changing the color: $(element).effect("highlight", {color: 'blue'}, 3000);

Comment: @RaviRam - perfect!

Answer (score 96):

If you want to specifically animate the background color of an element, I believe you need to include jQueryUI framework. Then you can do:

```
$('#myElement').animate({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'}, 'slow');
```

jQueryUI has some built-in effects that may be useful to you as well.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: I had to include "jQuery Color" for this, which is also in the jquery docs (_"(For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)"_).

Comment: `'slow'` can be replaced by seconds... where 1000 equals to 1 second... and so on.

Answer (score 29):

I know that the question was how to do it with jQuery, but you can achieve the same affect with simple CSS and just a little jQuery...

For example, you have a div with a 'box' class, add the following CSS:

```css
.box {
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
```

and then use the `AddClass` function to add another class with a different background color like 'box highlighted' or something like that with the following CSS:

```css
.box.highlighted {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baaLYB

Comment: Cool solution. Thank you.

Comment: This is a great solution that works without any additional libraries and is natively supported in all modern browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Usually you can use the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to manipulate arbitrary CSS properties, but for background colors you need to use the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/color/). Once you include this plugin, you can use something like others have indicated `$('div').animate({backgroundColor: '#f00'})` to change the color.

As others have written, some of this can be done using the jQuery UI library as well.

Answer (score 10):

Using jQuery only (no UI library/plugin). Even jQuery can be easily eliminated

```
//Color row background in HSL space (easier to manipulate fading)
$('tr').eq(1).css('backgroundColor','hsl(0,100%,50%');

var d = 1000;
for(var i=50; i<=100; i=i+0.1){ //i represents the lightness
    d  += 10;
    (function(ii,dd){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('tr').eq(1).css('backgroundColor','hsl(0,100%,'+ii+'%)'); 
        }, dd);    
    })(i,d);
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5NB3s/2/

- SetTimeout increases the lightness from 50% to 100%, essentially making the background white (you can choose any value depending on your color).
- SetTimeout is wrapped in an anonymous function for it to work properly in a loop ( [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171666/781695) )

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your browser support, you could use a css animation. Browser support is IE10 and up for CSS animation. This is nice so you don't have to add jquery UI dependency if its only a small easter egg. If it is integral to your site (aka needed for IE9 and below) go with the jquery UI solution.

```
.your-animation {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-animation: your-animation-name 1s ease 0s 1 alternate !important;
}
//You have to add the vendor prefix versions for it to work in Firefox, Safari, and Opera.
@-webkit-keyframes your-animation-name {
    from { background-color: #5EB4FE;}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
-moz-animation: your-animation-name 1s ease 0s 1 alternate !important;
}
@-moz-keyframes your-animation-name {
    from { background-color: #5EB4FE;}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
-ms-animation: your-animation-name 1s ease 0s 1 alternate !important;
}
@-ms-keyframes your-animation-name {
    from { background-color: #5EB4FE;}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
-o-animation: your-animation-name 1s ease 0s 1 alternate !important;
}
@-o-keyframes your-animation-name {
    from { background-color: #5EB4FE;}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
animation: your-animation-name 1s ease 0s 1 alternate !important;
}
@keyframes your-animation-name {
    from { background-color: #5EB4FE;}
    to {background-color: #fff;}
}
```

Next create a jQuery click event that adds the `your-animation` class to the element you wish to animate, triggering the background fading from one color to another:

```
$(".some-button").click(function(e){
    $(".place-to-add-class").addClass("your-animation");
});
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Here's **[Demo in JSfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/wwe0axzj/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a super simple jQuery plugin to accomplish something similar to this. I wanted something really light weight (it's 732 bytes minified), so including a big plugin or UI was out of the question for me. It's still a little rough around the edges, so feedback is welcome.

You can checkout the plugin here: https://gist.github.com/4569265.

Using the plugin, it would be a simple matter to create a highlight effect by changing the background color and then adding a `setTimeout` to fire the plugin to fade back to the original background color.

Comment: Dominik P: thanks for your 'little' plugin. It suits my needs well!

Answer (score 3):

To fade between 2 colors using only simple javascript:

```
function Blend(a, b, alpha) {
  var aa = [
        parseInt('0x' + a.substring(1, 3)), 
        parseInt('0x' + a.substring(3, 5)), 
        parseInt('0x' + a.substring(5, 7))
    ];

  var bb = [
        parseInt('0x' + b.substring(1, 3)), 
        parseInt('0x' + b.substring(3, 5)), 
        parseInt('0x' + b.substring(5, 7))
    ];

  r = '0' + Math.round(aa[0] + (bb[0] - aa[0])*alpha).toString(16);
  g = '0' + Math.round(aa[1] + (bb[1] - aa[1])*alpha).toString(16);
  b = '0' + Math.round(aa[2] + (bb[2] - aa[2])*alpha).toString(16);

  return '#'
        + r.substring(r.length - 2)
        + g.substring(g.length - 2)
        + b.substring(b.length - 2);
}

function fadeText(cl1, cl2, elm){
  var t = [];
  var steps = 100;
  var delay = 3000;

  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    (function(j) {
         t[j] = setTimeout(function() {
          var a  = j/steps;
          var color = Blend(cl1,cl2,a);
          elm.style.color = color;
         }, j*delay/steps);
    })(i);
  }

  return t;
}

var cl1 = "#ffffff";
var cl2 = "#c00000";
var elm = document.getElementById("note");
T  = fadeText(cl1,cl2,elm);
```

Source: http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/fade_text.htm

Answer (score 0):

javascript fade to white without jQuery or other library:

```
<div id="x" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,105)">hello world</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gEvent=setInterval("toWhite();", 100);
function toWhite(){
    var obj=document.getElementById("x");
    var unBlue=10+parseInt(obj.style.backgroundColor.split(",")[2].replace(/\D/g,""));
    if(unBlue>245) unBlue=255;
    if(unBlue<256) obj.style.backgroundColor="rgb(255,255,"+unBlue+")";
    else clearInterval(gEvent)
}
</script>
```

In printing, yellow is minus blue, so starting with the 3rd rgb element (blue) at less than 255 starts out with a yellow highlight. Then the `10+` in setting the `var unBlue` value increments the minus blue until it reaches 255.