# setTimeout and anonymous function problem

Tags: javascript

This is my code, SetOpacity get invoked with wrong values, why?

```
function SetOpacity(eID, opacity){                  
   eID.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
   eID.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
}
function fade(eID, startOpacity, endOpacity){           
    var timer = 0;
    if (startOpacity < endOpacity) { 
       for (var i = startOpacity; i <= endOpacity; i++) {
           setTimeout(function() {SetOpacity(eID, i);}, timer * 30);
           timer++;
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should work:

```
for (var i = startOpacity; i <= endOpacity; i++) {
    (function(opacity) {
        setTimeout(function() {SetOpacity(eID, opacity);}, timer * 30);
    })(i);
    timer++;
}
```

This works as follows:

- inside the loop you create an anonymous function (`function(...){...}`) and immediately call it with a parameter (that's why there are parentheses around `function(){}`, so you can call it by adding `()` at the end and passing parameters)
- parameters passed to this anonymous function (in this case `i`, which is `opacity` inside the function) are local to this anonymous function, so they don't change during the next iterations of the loop, and you can safely pass them to another anonymous function (the first parameter in `setTimeout`)

Your original version didn't work because:

- your function that is passed to `setTimeout` holds a *reference* to the variable `i` (not the *value* of it), and it resolves its value only when this function is called, which is not at the time of adding it to `setTimeout`
- the value of this variable gets changed in the loop, and before even the first `setTimeout` executes, `i` will have reached `endOpacity` (the last value from the `for` loop)

Unfortunately JavaScript only has function scope, so it won't work if you create the variable inside the loop and assign a new actual value, because whenever there is some `var` inside a function, those variables are created at the time of function execution (and are `undefined` by default). The only (easy) way to create new scope is to create a function (which may be anonymous) and create new variables inside it (parameters are variables too).

Comment: +1 - I've also started with an anonymous function. looking again, I guess yours is more elegant.

Comment: can you explain the thing with the (i) ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a closure issue. By the time you run the function, `i` is already at `endOpacity`. This will work, by creating another closure:

```
function SetOpacityTimeout(eID, opacity, timer){
  setTimeout(function() {SetOpacity(eID, opacity);}, timer * 30);
}

function fade(eID, startOpacity, endOpacity){           
    var timer = 0;
    if (startOpacity < endOpacity) {
       for (var i = startOpacity; i <= endOpacity; i++) {
          SetOpacityTimeout(eID,i,timer);
          timer++;
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? `var opacity` is still in the same scope as `i`, so it should still break, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Kobi has the right idea on the problem. I suggest you use an interval instead, though.

Here's an example: (Your SetOpacity function remains the same, I left it out here.)

```
function fade(eID, startOpacity, endOpacity){
    var opacity = startOpacity;
    SetOpacity(eID, opacity);

    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        opacity++;
        SetOpacity(eID, opacity);

        // Stop the interval when done
        if (opacity === endOpacity)
            window.clearInterval(interval);
    }, 30);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is am example I used with jquery. "menuitem" is the itemclass and jquery checks the "recentlyOut" class to see if it needs to slide back up.

The code speaks for itself.

```
$(".menuitem").mouseenter(
function(){
    $(this).addClass("over").removeClass("out").removeClass("recentlyOut");
    $(this).children(".sub").slideDown();
}); 
    $(".menuitem").mouseleave(
function(){

    $(this).addClass("out").addClass("recentlyOut").removeClass("over");
    setTimeout(function()
        {
            var bool = $(".recentlyOut").hasClass("over");
            if (!bool)
            {
    $(".recentlyOut").removeClass("recentlyOut").children(".sub").slideUp();
            }
        }
    , 400);
}
    );
```