# Dynamically set events and closure

Tags: javascript

This is a follow up question to my previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171602/settimeout-and-anonymous-function-problem):
I have this object:

```
var myObject {
 init: function(){

        for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            image = new Image();
.
.
.
            image.onmouseover = this.Fade(this, 70, 100,1);
            image.onmouseout = this.Fade(this, 100, 70,0);
         }
    },

SetOpacity: function (eID, opacity){                   
       eID.style.opacity = opacity / 100; 
       eID.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')'; 
    } ,
    fade: function (eID, startOpacity, endOpacity){            
        var timer = 0; 
        if (startOpacity < endOpacity) {  
          for (var i = startOpacity; i <= endOpacity; i++) { 
             (function(opacity) { 
                setTimeout(function() {SetOpacity(eID, opacity);}, timer * 30); 
             })(i); 
             timer++; 
           }     
        }            
    } 
}
```

Do I need to define closures on the events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Otherwise, the `image` variable will be shared by all three sets mouse handlers, and all of the animations will happen to the last image  (even if you mouseover a different image).

Also, in your `setTimeout` callback, you should be writing `MySlideshow.setOpacity`.

**EDIT**: Your code (`image.onmouseover = this.Fade(this, 70, 100,1)`) is *calling* the `Fade` method and assigning the function that it returns to the `onmouseover` property.  Since the `Fade` method doesn't return a function, it doesn't work.

You need to change it to `image.onmouseover = function() { MySlideShow.Fade(this, 70, 100, 1); };`.
That won't work as expected either unless you put it in a separate function.

Comment: I also get 'Not implemented' error in IE on line:
image.onmouseover = this.fade(this, 70, 100, 1);

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.