# Using a variable with changing value in setTimeout function approach?

Tags: javascript

Please let me know if I'm coming at this block on a wrong angle. I have a series of functions I'd like to fire off, and I'd like to be able to set them all up in a loop.

```
for(var jj = 0; jj<monster.frames.length;jj++){
    setTimeout(
        functionName(jj),
        1000*jj
    );
}
```

The problem is that when that when `functionName(jj)` is exectuted, it's being passed the value of `jj` which by that time has been changed to the last loop iteration value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413916/javascript-closure-immediate-evaluation

Comment: duplicate-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171602/settimeout-and-anonymous-function-problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to ensure the inner function has a new variable for every iteration. The easiest way to do this is to create a self-executing anonymous function which receives the variable as an argument. You also need to fix the way you are calling the function - right now you register the return value of `functionName(jj)` as a callback. This would only be ok if that function actually returned a function.

```
for(var jj = 0; jj<monster.frames.length;jj++){
    (function(jj) {
        setTimeout(
            function() { functionName(jj); },
            1000*jj
        );
    })(jj);
}
```

You can also use *partial application* to create a new function. However, old browsers do not support `Function.prototype.bind` so you'd have to add a shim for it.

```
for(var jj = 0; jj<monster.frames.length; jj++){
    setTimeout(functionName.bind(this, jj), 1000*jj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
for(var jj = 0; jj < monster.frames.length; jj++)
{
    (function(x)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            functionName(x)
        }, 1000 * x);
    })(jj);
}
```