# Adding delay on loading each row in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading data of HTML table dynamically from Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < StudentsList.length; i++) {
        LoadRow(StudentsList[i]);
    }

});
function LoadRow(student) {
        setTimeout(function (student) {
         $("#tbl tbody").append("<tr class='trStyleSummary'><td>" + student.Name + "</td></tr>");
         }, 1000);
}
```

I want the table to load rows one by one with delay.

How do I do that? I tried `SetTimeout` with 1sec, But for some reason, its not working. The table is loading entirely after 1 second.

Comment: What problems did you have with set time out?

Comment: @Ian:Updated the post with answer for your comment.

Comment: how are you calling LoadRow, is there only one row. Share a bit more code ;)

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary:updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because append is getting called at n:1000 for each row. Try following code, it will solve your problem, but it certainly is not a best approach.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < StudentsList.length; i++) {
        LoadRow(StudentsList[i],i);
    }

});
function LoadRow(student,n) {
        setTimeout(function (student) {
         $("#tbl tbody").append("<tr class='trStyleSummary'><td>" + student.Name + "</td></tr>");
         }, 1000*n);
}
```

Comment: It says student.Name is undefinded. Any idea?

Comment: console.log(student) will reveal if that student really has a Name property

Comment: Inside the LoadRow() i am able to get the name. But inside settimeout function , the name is undefined

Comment: It is because of scope. Solution and explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171602/settimeout-and-anonymous-function-problem

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzLQD/)***</kbd>

*jQuery*

```
$("tbody tr").each(function () {
   $(this).fadeIn($(this).index() * offset);
});
```

<kbd>***[Link to the result](http://jsfiddle.net/SzLQD/embedded/result/)***</kbd>

***Hope this is what you are looking for...!!***

Answer (score 0):

`SetTimeout` just runs things once.  What you want is `SetInterval` so it runs like a clock.  This is how I would solve it:

```
// From your example before
function LoadRow(student) {
  $("#tbl tbody").append("<tr class='trStyleSummary'><td>" + student.Name + "</td></tr>");
}    

// Say for example you have these as your students: 
var students = [{ Name: 'joe' }, { Name: 'matt' }, { Name: 'sherry' }];

// The index of the last student
var l = students.length;

// Start a Count index
var i = 0;

// START!
var t = setInterval(function(){

  // Load one
  LoadRow( students[i] );

  // Increment up
  i++;

  // Check if all is done, if so stop and clear out
  if (i == l) clearInterval(t);

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should try this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadRow(StudentsList);        
});

function LoadRow(list) {
    if(list != undefined || list.length < 1) {
        // done
        // do something else
        return;
    }

    // Get first item
    const student = list.shift();

    $("#tbl tbody").append(`<tr class='trStyleSummary'>td>${student.Name}</td></tr>`);
    setTimeout(function (student) {
        // Recall the function after 0.15 second
        LoadRow(list);
     }, 150);
}
```