# Fading colors with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regular color change using jquery, but I'd like to have it so it has a smooth color change. At the moment, the code changes the color of a link on hover and then removes it when the mouse is removes. I have seen one tutorial but it doesn't explain it and it does not look like my current code. This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#link1,#link2,#link3").hover(function() {
$(this).addClass("red");
},function(){
 $(this).removeClass("red");   }); });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link1,#link2,#link3").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: "#990000" });
  },function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" });
  }); 
});
```

Note though, you need either the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) included for color animations to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I used this plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/node/467/release and all is well

Comment: I have another question, how would I make the first hover animation instant and the change back to the original slow? It's just I saw it on a website and thought it looked pretty cool.

Comment: @Jake - you can add a duration, for example:  `$(this).stop().animate({ color: "#990000" }, 50);` for a quick animation on hover, and `$(this).stop().animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" }, 500);` for a slow one back

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i can't use a 0 value though, so is there a way to make it absolutely instant? Thanks so much for all you've done so far though

Comment: @Jake - yup, to make it totally instant, use `.css()`, like this: `$(this).stop().css({ color: "#990000" });`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "smooth" color change then perhaps you are asking for color animation, check out this thread:

[How do you fade in/out a background color using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way without using the extra jquery plugin. In fact, this is mostly done with css. Make 2 divs on top of each other and fade the top one. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Jny9x/