# Fade color answer trick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

For example when I copy the link from an answer and access it, a nice block of color appears to highlight the answer and then is fading out. How this is done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you fade in/out a background color using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery) ... please use the search before you ask a question.

Comment: Use your imagination and Firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks at the hash, selects that answer, and then animates the background color. Either use jQuery UI or add the [Colors plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to be able to animate colors.

This is what the code may look like...

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash) {
   var answer = $('#answer-' + hash.substr(1)),
       originalBackgroundColor = answer.css('backgroundColor'); 

   // This class changes the background colur.
   // Best to keep style stuff in the CSS layer.
   answer
   .addClass('linked')
   .animate({
       backgroundColor: originalBackgroundColor
   }, 1000);

   // You may optionally remove the added class
   // in the callback of the above animation.
}
```