# How to fade background instead of just change color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have it so my background fades to colors, not just changes. I'd also like to have it repeat if possible!

I'm using JQuery right now to change the CSS of the body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var bgColor = ["#FF0000", "#FF00A6", "#FF00FF"];
     var i = 0;
     var bgRotate = setInterval(function(){    
         $('body').css({'backgroundColor' : bgColor[[i]]});
         i++;
      }, 1000);   

     });
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33VgU/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor there's a jquery plugin and a CSS only answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use CSS3 animations for this using `@keyframes` as this question is also tagged as CSS so would like to post one

Everything is self explanatory, only about this line `animation: demo 3s infinite linear;` is nothing but a short hand of 4 properties, namely

- `animation-name`
- `animation-duration`
- `animation-iteration-count`
- `animation-timing-function`

Here, I've used `infinite` so it keeps iterating, and am using `linear` for a consistent animation.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/26jDD/)

```
html, body, div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    -webkit-animation: demo 3s infinite linear; 
    animation: demo 3s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
        background: #FF0000;
    }
    33% {
        background: #0f0;
    }
    100% {
        background: #f0f;
    }
}


@keyframes demo {
    0% {
        background: #FF0000;
    }
    33% {
        background: #0f0;
    }
    100% {
        background: #f0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, much better than JS.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). They are much smoother than jQuery's transitions and features all of CSS' usual benefits (Cascading, no JS required, etc.)

```
body { transition: background-color 1s }
```

To make it repeat, do this:

```
$('body').css({'backgroundColor' : bgColor[i%bgColor.length]});
```

It does a remainder-of-division (modulo) operation on the array length.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using css3 :)

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes blink {
    0%   { background:red; }
    50%  { background:green;}
    100% { background:red; }
 }
  body{
 -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
 -moz-animation:    blink 1s infinite;
 -ms-animation:     blink 1s infinite;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery) question

Using  jQueryUI framework you can do :

```
$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'}, 'slow');
```

Comment: this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery

Comment: Yes, It works now. It used to be [1], instead of a link. Or did you edit it?

Comment: Edited it just before you ask the comment :)

Comment: Oh... That explains it. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try to animate it with jQuery's `animate()` method.. Let's say that you have a DIV with the CSS setting

```
#yourDiv{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and you want to animate it to black color over 5 seconds, after clicking on a DIV with id *darkenButton*. You can use the click event:

```
$('#darkenButton').click(function(){
    $('#yourDiv').animate({
        background-color: '#000000'
    }, 5000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .animate() instead of .css(). And for repeating, you have to make a function:

```
function changeColor(i) {
    var bgColor = ["#FF0000", "#FF00A6", "#FF00FF"];
    if(i > bgColor.length) { i = 0; }
    $('body').animate({'backgroundColor' : bgColor[[i]]});
    var bgRotate = setTimeout(function() {    
        changeColor(++i);
    }, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply change the `var i's` value when it reaches the end of `array`, check this http://jsfiddle.net/33VgU/3, this will repeats the backgrounds infinitely, and if you change color randomly than use `Math.random` function to get value of `var i`.

Comment: for fading you can use animate() function instead of css().

Comment: Then you should fix your answer. Or delete it because the are already answers that say that