# jQuery: eliminate white screen "pause" between animations

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout, cross-fade

I have just discovered **[Barba.js](http://barbajs.org/)** and find it very useful. It provides smooth transitions between URLs of the same website.

I have put together a **[Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FlsME0Iz7u191lC0)** consisting of two pages (index.html and about.html) that are loaded smoothly, with the help of jQuery’s `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var transEffect = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
    start: function() {
      this.newContainerLoading.then(val => this.fadeInNewcontent($(this.newContainer)));
    },
    fadeInNewcontent: function(nc) {
      nc.hide();
      var _this = this;
      $(this.oldContainer).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(() => {
        nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
        nc.fadeIn(1000, function() {
          _this.done();
        });
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: 300
        },1000);
      });
    }
  });
  Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
    return transEffect;
  }
  Barba.Pjax.start();
});
```

The problem with this animations is that there is a *white screen interval* between them.

How could I eliminate this interval, to make the transition smoother? By "smoother" I mean similar to **[this one](https://antoni.de/) (click "view case")**.

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow, if you've not figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white screen is the body color because you're using `promise().done(..)` `jquery` apply the `fadeIn` after the `fadeOut` finish so the body color will appear. So, this is an example sort of similar to what you have:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .One{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #476d80;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .Two{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #03A9F4;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.one').click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function(){
                $('div.Two').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="One"></div>
<div class="Two"></div>
```

like you see in the example above the white screen also appears so if you don't want that just don't use `promise().done(..)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.one').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
        $('div.Two').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

you can edit your code like this:

```
$(this.oldContainer).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(() => {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 300
    },1000);
});
nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
nc.fadeIn(1000, function() {
    _this.done();
});
```

Comment: I have used the script you provided on **[this page](http://code-love.tk/demos/prop/)**. Click on "Studiu de caz" to see the transition. It has improved a lot indeed *but* the script has introduced a bug: clicking the **browser's back button** ruins the homepage slider.

Comment: unless you have other parts of a fulling working app in place, such as a state manager, or router, or both, that is syncing with local storage and the history object, then, yes, things like the browser's back button are going to cause you trouble. This is a fairly complicated feature you are asking for, your app will need more engineering to make all of this possible, and this is exceeding the scope of a single Q on SO.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `setTimeout()` to overlap the fade out and fade in? That should keep it from blanking out completely, which want to avoid.

You could try something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var transEffect = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
    start: function() {
      this.newContainerLoading.then(val => this.fadeInNewcontent($(this.newContainer)));
    },
    fadeInNewcontent: function(nc) {
      nc.hide();
      var _this = this;

      // manipulate these values
      let fadeOutTime = 1000;
      let fadeInTime = 1000;
      let overlapTime = 100;

      $(this.oldContainer).fadeOut(fadeOutTime);

      // use setTimeout() to begin fadeIn before fadeOut is completely done
      setTimeout(function () {
        nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
        nc.fadeIn(fadeInTime, function() {
          _this.done();
        });

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: 300
        }, fadeInTime);

      }, fadeOutTime - overlapTime)

    }
  });
  Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
    return transEffect;
  }
  Barba.Pjax.start();
});
```

NOTE: This is just a stab at it, the plunker is helpful, but it's hard to see the animation in action.

**UPDATE**

I think you'll need something like the above, but if you want to fade in/out of black, then you'll also want to do something like create a div wrapper around all of your content within your body and give that div the background color of your app,  #eff3f6, and then making the actual body background black. You'll have some work to get the exact effect you desire, but something like that or in the SO link in the comments below should help.

Comment: By "smoother" I mean similar to **[this one](https://antoni.de/)** (wait 2, 3 seconds, then click "view case"). I mean, an "invisible transition".

Comment: You mean that it fades in and out of black instead of white? Or one that fades in/out of a certain direction?

Comment: I am looking for *the same effect* as at the address I have showed you. I do not no how do do that. It might work. How do I fade to black?

Comment: Yep, that is a beautiful effect. However, working a full solution to provide the exact same functional feature would exceed the purpose of StackOverflow. I would take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967815/how-do-you-fade-in-out-a-background-color-using-jquery, and other similar questions on StackOverflow. This will take you in the right direction, but you'll have to put together the exact solution. Also, have you inspected the sources and the html on that page you like? You should be able to find what they're doing by inspection.

Comment: This is hat we have Plunker for.

Comment: Do you know any (superior) alternatives to Barba.js?

Comment: Actually, offhand, I do not. I would search npmjs.com for transitions, animations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this version of the script:

```
$(function(){
    var transEffect = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
    start: function() {
      this.newContainerLoading.then(val => this.fadeInNewcontent($(this.newContainer)));
    },
    fadeInNewcontent: function(nc) {
      var _this = this;
      nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
      nc.show().promise().done(() => {
        $(this.oldContainer).fadeOut(50);
        if (!isMobile.any()) {
          $('html, body').delay(100).animate({
            scrollTop: 200
          },700);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
    return transEffect;
  }
  Barba.Pjax.start();
});
```

It is better, but not smooth enough. See the the effect on a **[real life project](http://code-love.tk/demos/prop/)**. How can I improve it?